# Reading local filestream with fallback to other source

Tags: node.js, stream, promise, fs

I store files in Amazon S3, but also maintain a local file cache. When I need a file I want to check the cache first. I want to avoid testing for local file existance before reading, both because fs.exists will be deprecated and the file can actually be deleted between the exists-check and the file read.

I want to use promises and streams. The below example has a fallback to another local file. My real code will have S3 as fallback.

Would the below be a good solution?
The only way I found to get information of a failed read was to hook up an error handler to the stream. Once I get the "readable" event I unhook my temporary error handler.

I also wonder If I really need to unhook the handler when I use "once" to hook it up.

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');

function tryToReadLocalFile() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let rs = fs.createReadStream('./test1.txt');

    let errorListener = function(err) {
      reject(err);
    };

    rs.once('error', errorListener)

    rs.on('readable', () => {
      rs.removeListener('error', errorListener);
      resolve(rs)
    });
  });    
}

function tryToReadAnotherFile() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let rs = fs.createReadStream('./test2.txt');

    let errorListener = function(err) {
      reject(err);
    };

    rs.once('error', errorListener)

    rs.on('readable', () => {
      rs.removeListener('error', errorListener);
      resolve(rs)
    });    
  });
}

tryToReadLocalFile()
.catch(function(err) {
  if(err.code === 'ENOENT') {
    console.log('test1.txt not found. Fallback to test2.txt')

    //Reading from another file as a test. Should read from S3 as fallback
    return tryToReadAnotherFile();
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
}).then(function(file) {
  console.log('writing to test.txt');
  let ws = fs.createWriteStream('./test.txt');
  file.pipe(ws);
});
```

---------- edit -->

I have now implemented a more compact version of the above. I would still be grateful for any input on this, though. Is this a good way to solve this?

As you can see I don't bother to check for ENOENT anymore. Whatever the error is, I want to fall back to S3.

```
function getFileFromStorageP(options) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let rs = fs.createReadStream(path.join(env.fsp.cacheDir, options.fileId));
    rs.once('error', (err) => {reject(err)});
    rs.once('readable', () => {resolve(rs)});
  }).catch(function(err) {
    return srvS3.download({
      fileId: options.fileId
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll post an answer for others to read..

The above solution is now implemented and works great. I haven't found any easier way to get hold of the error, though.